# Phrasing a question about technical leadership readiness

Tags: discussion

I'd like to pose a question, which goes something like this:

'What are some signs that one is ready for a technical leadership role'

or

'How does one know that they're ready for a technical leadership role'

Does this sound like it'd be a fit here? If not, is there a way to phrase the question so it'd work?

Answer (score 1):

This question would be closed as off-topic because it is asking for career advice.

> Questions seeking career or education advice are off topic on
>   Programmers. They are only meaningful to the asker and do not generate
>   lasting value for the broader programming community. Furthermore, in
>   most cases, any answer is going to be a subjective opinion that may
>   not take into account all the nuances of a (your) particular
>   circumstance.

There is no way to rephrase this question to be on-topic.

Hypothetically speaking: even if this question were on-topic, it would certainly be too broad.

Related reading: [Why was my question closed as off topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6488/)

Comment: Although, this is also clearly a programming related question. I remember reading an answer which explained this type of thing and what's actually acceptable when programming / career intersect in a question, although I wouldn't know where to find it.

Comment: @CanadianCoder I know which meta post you are talking about but I do not have the link handy. Regardless of whether it is strictly on-topic or not, you will likely have poor results and get frustrated if you ask. I think a better place to ask would be Programmers chat ([The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard)).